# Create custom css file using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a custom css file with php.

My goal is that users can create there own look for my site.
I’m think that the user will fill out a form and than use fopen, fwrite and fclose. Thats what im thinking anyways.

I’m new to PHP so i’m not sure if this is the way to go. I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some feedback. Maybe you know a better way?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $background_color = "background-color:".$_POST['background-color'];
  $font_size = "font-size:".$_POST['font-size'].";";

  $content = "body{".$background_color.$font_size."}";

  $file = fopen("USERNAME.css","w");
  fwrite($file,$content);
  fclose($file);
};
?>

<form method="post">
  background-color: <input type="text" name="background-color"><br>
  font-size: <input type="text" name="font-size"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Use javascript instead

Comment: generally this kind of thing would be database driven i.e. users choose their background color and that gets saved into a field in the database tied to their profile

Comment: yeah.. That sounds like a good idea. I can see that working thanks!

Comment: Just use a php file as a css. You just have to set the header to `Content-Type: text/css` and the users browser gonna save it to cache.

Comment: You have some curly quotes happening like `“ ”` and `’ ’` and that will break your code (probably using Word to code with). Plus, I wouldn't let direct user input, but use presets. What if they enter *"I don't know the size/color?!"* ? Think about it ;-)

Comment: Plus, your first conditional statement will never happen. There is no name attribute for an input to match it. You also can't use hyphens for variables `$background-color` PHP will see that as *background MINUS color*. Same for `$font-size` - *font MINUS size*. Use underscores instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have some curly quotes happening, such as `“ ”` and `’ ’` and that will break your code (probably using some type of Word processor software to code with, use a code editor).

Now, I wouldn't let direct user input, but use presets. What if they enter *"I don't know the size/color?!"* as text? *Think about it.*

Plus, your first conditional statement will never happen because there is no name attribute for an input to match it.

Furthermore, you should not use hyphens for variables seperators `$background-color`. PHP will see that as "background **MINUS** color".

The same thing goes for `$font-size` which PHP will translate that as "font **MINUS** size". Use underscores as seperators instead.

What I would do in your place is use presets from `<select>` which is what I used as an example below. You can use radio buttons also; the choice is yours.

I also spotted another error in your code in this line which would not add a semi-colon at the end of the first CSS declaration:

```
$background-color = "background-color:".$_POST['background-color'];
```

It would need an extra semi-colon (and a space, not crucial):

```
$background_color = "background-color:".$_POST['background-color']. "; ";
```

Here's a rewrite that you can use, which I might add works.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $background_color = "background-color:".$_POST['background-color']. "; ";
  $font_size = "font-size:".$_POST['font-size'].";";

  $content = "body{".$background_color.$font_size."}";

  $file = fopen("USERNAME.css","w");
  fwrite($file,$content);
  fclose($file);
};
// The semi-colon after your closing brace can be safely omitted.
?>

<form method="post">

<select name="background-color">

    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="#000000">Black</option>

</select>

Font size:
<select name="font-size">

    <option value="10pt">10 pt.</option>
    <option value="12pt">12 pt.</option>
    <option value="14pt">14 pt.</option>

</select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Having selected "Black" and "10 pt." from the selects, produced the following in USERNAME.css:

`body{background-color:#000000; font-size:10pt;}`

Your present code (with the curly quotes changed to regular quotes), produced the following:

`body{background-color:greenfont-size:5;}`

which would not be valid CSS.